# Rolling a lawn "sports field" in late July due to ruts caused by lawn mowers cutting too soon after a heavy rain, 8 ton roller bad idea?

Tags: lawn

The weight of the roller is way too heavy, the grass is perennial rye and kentucky blue. The soil is predominantly clay with several years of top dressing using mushroom compost and a course sand core aerated prior to top dressing. Rolling was not only isolated to the rutted area; the entire field was rolled, which in my books was not required, because now the entire field has been compacted. After the rolling a light aeration with a very small slit aerator was used. It should have been a much bigger slit aerator and done quite aggressively. I have a good idea of what this will do to the turf in the coming months. What can I do to try and repair the damage that such a heavy roller has the potential of doing? There is no dedicated irrigation system on these fields, and the rolling was done a few days after a very heavy sustained rain storm.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the roller. For a home owner , a few hundred pounds is good enough with a roller of roughly 3' length and 2' diameter (about 600 lb if full of water , usually they were not totally filled).